# Fetching reviews and ratings from Shopify API

Tags: shopify, review

I need to get latest reviews from Shopify and it's ratings.
I found official Shopify reviews app with code snippet
which needs to be placed in theme template file, but there seems
to be no way to get these reviews through API or through webhooks.

Is there any other app for reviews in Shopify with open API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yotpo](https://apps.shopify.com/yotpo-social-reviews) seems to have an open API: http://apidocs.yotpo.com/reference

Comment: it seems there are lots of people asking for a webhook for the Shopify review app, including me :)

Answer (score 0):

I asked Shopify to create a webhook for their review app but the response was that they do not integrate with third party apps, unfortunately.

I'm not sure about getting historical reviews, but you can capture reviews that are created in the review form by adding an additional submit event handler in your script tag and submitting the data to your server via XHR.